# "Split"/ "generate" operation in sequence?

Tags: system.reactive, rx-java

I'm trying to find an operation in RxJava which would fit the next sequence operation:

[A], [B], [C] -> Aa, Ab, Ac, Ba, Bb, Bc, Ca, Cb, Cc

The practical usecase being that I have an Observable that contains a list of items which I'm trying to convert into Observable emitting flattened items from the lists.

Like this:

```
Observable<List<Item>> ---> Observable<Item>
```

I can't seem to find a fitting RxJava operation that would do something like that - there is flatMap() which is the exact inverse of what I want, but no "generate" or "mapToMany" operation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flatMap() does sound like what you are looking for:

```java
// This assumes that generating originalObservable is not under your control
// and is returned from some other API call you are making.
List<Item> originalList = Arrays.asList(new Item(), new Item(), new Item());
Observable<List<Item>> originalObservable = Observable.just(originalList);

Observable<Item> itemObservable =
        originalObservable
                .flatMap(new Func1<List<Item>, Observable<Item>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Item> call(List<Item> items) {
                        return Observable.from(items);
                    }
                });
```

If you actually have access the originalList (as opposed to originalObservable from some other API call), you could use from() to create an Observable from it:

```java
Observable<Item> itemObservable = Observable.from(originalList);
```

I'm not sure how that relates to your original sequence ([A], [B], [C] -> Aa, Ab, Ac, Ba, Bb, Bc, Ca, Cb, Cc) since I'm not sure where small a, b and c come from. If they are standalone values that don't need capital A, B and C to generate them, then again flatMap() is what you want.

```java
Observable<String> result =
        Observable
                .just("A", "B", "C")
                .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> call(String s) {
                        return Observable
                                .just(s + "a", s + "b", s + "c");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I explained that poorly - I have a sequence of lists of items which I want to flatten to just a continious sequence of items inside those lists. It seems flatMap might be exactly what I want and I just misunderstood the documentation.